# Recommendations about the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, exponential-function

I am studying differential equations and I am very surprised by how omnipresent the exponential function is. It pops up everywhere, but there isn't usually a lot of detail provided in introductory textbooks about how the solutions come up and why the exponential function has so much importance. One thing I find fascinating is how the exponential function has the characteristic that it is the same as its slope. I'd like to know more about it so that I can understand why it's so important.

I guess the main problem is that this would probably require going into some real analysis. As I said, I have some knowledge of ODEs, calculus and linear algebra (and I have worked a little bit with proofs). So I would be very grateful if I could get some recommendations from you to get deeper into the topic of exponential functions, perhaps analysis more broadly if that is required.

Comment: "One thing I find fascinating is how the exponential function has the characteristic that it is the same as its slope." That's a big part of why it shows up in differential equations so much.

Comment: Closely related to $f(x)=e^x$ satisfying the nice ODE $f'=f$ is the simplicity of its [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). You may want to study Taylor expansions/series for that reason. To know the other formula $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$ is a must as well.

Comment: Any physical model which has the rate of change of a quantity depending on the amount of that quantity generates an exponential solution. So nuclear decay rate, Newton's law of cooling, charge across a capacitor, pressure in a balloon ...

Comment: @Paul Compound interest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a completely satisfying abstract explanation of why the exponential function shows up so much but it requires some familiarity with [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra). Once you understand that language, the explanation is: $e^{\lambda x}$ is the unique (up to scale) [eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) for the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This says concretely that $e^{\lambda x}$ is the unique (up to scale) solution of

$$\frac{d}{dx} y(x) = \lambda y(x).$$

This turns out to completely explain the importance of exponentials for solving linear homogeneous constant-coefficient ODEs; abstractly and in one sentence, it's because exponentials [diagonalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization) any [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) which is a polynomial in $\frac{d}{dx}$. But one has to know quite a lot of linear algebra to make sense of this. For that you can consult any textbook on linear algebra; Axler's *[Linear Algebra Done Right](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319110799)* might be a good place to start.

Comment: There is also a generalization where $\lambda$ is replaced by a matrix which is important e.g. for studying the behavior of an autonomous differential equation $y' = F(y)$ at a fixed point and classifying equilibria into stable vs. unstable and so forth. I suppose the chain rule + the basic $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ is the most general thing one can say here but the eigenvector stuff above suffices for the linear homogeneous constant-coefficient stuff which I assume is what the OP is referring to.